# Do rails routing constraint regexps have implicit anchors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a route in my app that looks something like this:

```
match '/:id' => 'controller#action', :constraints => { :id => VALID_IDS }
```

where VALID_IDS is a regexp whitelist like

```
/(good_id|another_good_id|a_valid_id)/
```

now it appears that the uri

```
/good_id_one
```

is NOT matching this constraint, even though

```
1.9.2p318 :004 > "good_id_one".match /^(good_id|another_good_id|a_valid_id)/
 => #<MatchData "good_id" 1:"good_id">
```

Why is that? I have a suspicion. [This guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) says that

> :constraints takes regular expressions with the restriction that regexp anchors can’t be used.
>   However, note that you don’t need to use anchors because all routes are anchored at the start.

Is it also the case that rails adds an anchor at the *end* of the regexp? That would explain what I'm seeing, because

```
1.9.2p318 :006 > "good_id_one".match /^(good_id|another_good_id|a_valid_id)$/
 => nil
```

However, I'm not sure that this suspicion is correct. Can anyone confirm or deny my hypothesis?

(p.s., `Rails 3.0.11, Ruby 1.9.2`)

Answer (score -1):

It's not because of the implicit anchor, it's because of the / at the end of your expression.

Try:

```
/(good_id|another_good_id|a_valid_id)
```

Comment: Sorry, that literal syntax was just for demonstration purposes. The regexp matcher is actually being constructed by Regexp.new("(good_id|another_good_id|a_valid_id)"). The slashes are not part of the regexp.

Comment: In that case, I think you need to have the / at the beginning.  Regexp.new("/(good_id|another_good_id|a_valid_id)") and this *is* because of the anchor.

Comment: What Rails is matching the regexp against is `params[:id]`, which doesn't include a leading `/`. If you add that then the route doesn't match *either* of the following paths: `/good_id`, `/good_id_one`.